# I'm in Playwright, how do I run specific test cases by tag in (CI) execution

Tags: github, continuous-integration, tags, project, playwright

Hi all I am working with Playwright and I have different projects inside defined in my playwright.config.ts (the data is fake because for privacy policies I can't share any of my work obviously).

projects: [
{
name: 'Carlino-Qa',
use: {
...devices['Desktop Edge'],
channel: 'msedge',
baseURL: 'https://qa.carlino.com/',
},
retries: 1,
},

```
    {
      name: 'Carlino-Dev',
      use: {
            ...devices['Desktop Edge'],
            channel: 'msedge', 
            baseURL: 'https://dev.carlino.com/'
          },
      retries: 1,
    },
    
    {
      name: 'Carlino-Portugal',
     ** testMatch: '@portugal'** 
      use: {
            ...devices['Desktop Edge'],
            channel: 'msedge', 
            baseURL: 'https://qa.carlino.portugal.com/'
          },
    },       
  ],
```

Note: my yml file is configured in such a way that when I manually run a workflow in github, I can tell it which project should run

### I want to execute my test cases in Github for Carlino-Portugal project, and when the execution starts I want to execute just only the test cases that has the @portugal tag.

I know that testMatch: is only able to match with folders and not tags. And I know that grep can be used, but can I use grep option for an individual project?

1. How can I configure my project to indicate that only test cases with this tag will run when it is executed?
2. Do you have any other strategies to recommend?

Thank you very much !

I tried npx playwright test --grep=@portugal and it worked.
I tried npx playwright test --project='Carlino-Portugal' and it works only when testMatch attribute is not defined for tags.
I tried to execute in github carlino-portugal project but it started the execution for every test case because the filter was not working

Comment: `npx playwright test --project='Carlino-Portugal'  --grep=@ portugal ` should work

Comment: "I tried `npx playwright test --grep=@portugal` and it worked" -- so you're good? What is the question/problem/issue here exactly?

Comment: I gather that you want options that work from your playwright.config.js and possibly that you don't want the grep element to be run from the command line and want it to happen whenever you run that project.

You say "And I know that grep can be used, but can I use grep option for an individual project?". The docs say it exists as a property in TestConfig so what happens if you try it with npx playwright test --project='Carlino-Portugal' ?

Comment: Correction: I meant TestProject rather than TestConfig - it is in both sets of docs which implies it can be set at either level, but the usage example on the TestProject docs is pretty poor.

Comment: Hello guys :) 
@hardkoded : True ! It's working in Local thanks. (follow next comments)

Comment: @ggorlen The issue was at the moment Github starts the execution ! Github was executing the whole projects defined and not only the one I wanted. Also, the project was running every test case instead the filtered by tag!

(follow next comments)

Comment: @@sahmeepee That's it. I want to run this project in Github, and the project must run only the test cases filtered by TAG. 

Next comment the solution sorry for the extensive messages

Comment: You might want to [edit] your post to clarify. If you have an answer, please post a [self answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: Instead of using testmatch for filtering the test cases that should be executed on my project. I used GREP in this way.

 {
      name: 'Carlino-Portugal',
      grep:  [/@tagExample/,/@tagExample2/]
      use: {
            ...devices['Desktop Edge'],
            channel: 'msedge', 
            baseURL: 'https://qa.carlino.portugal.com/'
          },
    },       

I tried using grep: '@tagexample' and it didn't work.

So after having this configuration, Github executes Carlino-Portugal project and all the test cases that has got this tag.

Hope it's clear for you too :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using testmatch for filtering the test cases that should be executed on my project. I used GREP in this way.

```
{ name: 'Carlino-Portugal', grep: [/@tagExample/,/@tagExample2/] use: { ...devices['Desktop Edge'], channel: 'msedge', baseURL: 'qa.carlino.portugal.com' }, },
```

I tried using grep: '@tagexample' and it didn't work. So after having this configuration, Github executes Carlino-Portugal project and all the test cases that has got this tag. Hope it's clear for you too :)

**Don't forget, you should have your .yml file configured if you want to execute an specific project in Github.**